# jQuery deferred AJAX call return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, jquery-deferred

I have a function, which will either return a cached template or if the template has not been cached - it will load it via AJAX and then return it. Here's what I've got:

```
var getTpl = function( name ) {

    var cached = cache.get( 'templates' ) || {};

    if( cached.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {

        console.log( 'template ' + name + '.mustache found in cache' );

        return cached[ name ];

    }

    else {

        console.log( 'requesting ' + name + '.mustache template via AJAX' );

        var tpl;

        $.ajax( {

            url: path.templates + '/' + name + '.mustache',
            async: false,
            success: function( data ) {

                tpl = data;

                var cached      = store.get( 'miniTemplates' ) || {};
                var newTemplate = {};

                newTemplate[ name ] = data;

                if( ! cached.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) cache.set( 'templates', _.extend( cached, newTemplate ) )

            },
            error: function() { tpl = false; }

        } );

        return tpl;

    }

}
```

This works fine. However, Chrome is complaining about:

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Therefore I wanted to switch to using `$.deferred`, but I can't wrap my head around it. How can I re-write the function above, so calling `getTpl` would always return a template (either form the cache or directly from the AJAX request)?

Comment: You can't, `getTpl` will have to return a promise\deferred if the template isn't cached.

Comment: so how come deferred is encouraged instead of async AJAX calls? it's very limiting. how can i restructure my function (maybe split it in two?) so it serves the same purpose as it does at the moment?

Comment: Simple, whatever you were going to do with the template, do it when the deferred is resolved, for ajax specifically the `success` callback is a good place to do it.

Comment: The warning message could be due to an XMLHttpRequest request within the main thread with the async flag set to false.

Comment: @Musa I can't run my code inside the `success` callback. The function needs to behave exactly the same way as it does right now - it MUST return a template.

Comment: That's why you HAVE to restructure your code. With async ajax there is no template available when the function returns.

Comment: How do I do it? Even pseudo code will be very helpful. The problem is, this is a part of a larger app, which is already live and I can't afford to change everything that's built around that function. Essentially, this function is called at the very beginning of the script to load all `*.mustache` templates into the cache, and then it's called each time a template is being rendered. I can's switch to the asynchronous mode, because it will fail for all the templates that have not been cached. Async is used here on purpose - to stop the execution of subsequent code until the template is loaded.

Comment: Make this method ALWAYS return a promise and you'll be in good shape. Otherwise, this problem can't be solved and you'll have to just get used to that warning happening, and other devs that use your app complaining about how bad it is.

Comment: Just one suggestion: For our company's structure, we have something like this for message strings; but the assumption is that in 100% of production code, it will never need to request from server. What we do is, the request is made *synchronously* (again, something you never want in production code) but also outputs a log message to the developer informing them that a particular object was not in the page's cached bundle as expected. This is only used as a fallback mechanism for cases where preloading didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use promise/deferred concept to achieve your needs

```
var getTpl = function( name ) {
   var promise;

    var cached = cache.get( 'templates' ) || {};

    if( cached.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {

        console.log( 'template ' + name + '.mustache found in cache' );

        var df = new $.Deferred();
        df.resolve(cached[ name ]);

        promise = df.promise();

    } else {
        console.log( 'requesting ' + name + '.mustache template via AJAX' );

        promise = $.ajax({
            url: path.templates + '/' + name + '.mustache'
        }).then(function(data) {
            tpl = data;

            var cached      = store.get( 'miniTemplates' ) || {};
            var newTemplate = {};

            newTemplate[ name ] = data;

            if( ! cached.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) cache.set( 'templates', _.extend( cached, newTemplate ) )

            return tpl;
        });

    }

    return promise;

}
```

Then, call your method like this:

```
getTpl('xyz')
    .then(function(template) {
        // you have the template, either from cache or fetched via ajax
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Looks like you're returning a Deferred instead of a promise when the value is in the cache.

Comment: In addition to the fix, the code will simplify by several lines, eg. `$.when(cached[name])` would create the required resolved promise, and `cached[name] = data;` would make the intermediate variable `newTemplate` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to appear to already be using underscore/lodash, you can make use of memoization rather than maintaining your own cache.

The beauty of promises is that you can access them again and again and they will always produce the same value:

```
var getTpl = _.memoize(function( name ) {
    console.log( 'requesting ' + name + '.mustache template via AJAX' );

    return $.ajax({
        url: path.templates + '/' + name + '.mustache'
    });
});
```

Yes, it really is that simple.

Then you can just use it like any other promise:

```
getTpl('myTemplate').then(function (template) {
    // use template
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Could not retrieve template.', error);
});
```